# Avoiding artefacts (gaps) between contiguous shapes in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

If I draw two squares side-by-side in TikZ, there will be a small gap between them at some zoom levels.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[black] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \fill[black] (1,0) rectangle (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: contiguous black squares]

Is there a way to avoid this gap without making each square slightly bigger / adding a thin stroke (as this feels like an ugly hack)?

Comment: It is possible that it is a function of the PDF viewer and the zoom level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I assume it is possible that it is a function of the PDF viewer and the zoom level.
- See my screenshot.
- You can maybe create an actual overlap to avoid that.
- In Adobe Reader, there is even an option for that.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In this case, in Adobe Reader, isn't it the `Smooth line art` option that matters?

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thanks for the comment. I did not test it but maybe you are right.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even consider that it might be an issue with the PDF renderer. But the squares render correctly in Chrome's built-in PDF viewer, for instance, which suggests your hypothesis is correct. I suppose adding manual overlap is the only way to get around this after all.